# Entity Framework Core 3 - Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am trying to map entities in Entity Framework Core and getting the following error. I have two main entities `Person` and `PersonNote` which have a one-to-many relationship.

One person can have many person notes. My method that I am trying to retrieve personotes does return a result but the fails when it is trying to map. I have defined two mappings as you can see in my post. One is to map PersonNote with Person so that AuthorName can be evaluated. The AuthorId in 
PersonNote related to Id in Person.

My model for PersonNote contains the AuthorName but the DataModel does not contain. I am trying to Map that value in the createmap function. Am I missing something

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nEntityQueryable`1 ->

I have defined the following models

```
    namespace Genistar.Organisation.Models.User
    {
        public class PersonNote
        {
            public PersonNote()
            {
                 Person = new HashSet<Person>();
            }

            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int PersonId { get; set; }
            public string Note { get; set; }
            public int AuthorId { get; set; }
            public string AuthorName { get; set; }
            public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
            public DateTime Created { get; set; }

            public ICollection<Person> Person { get; set; }
        }
    }

namespace Genistar.Organisation.Models.DataModels
{
        [Table(nameof(PersonNote), Schema = "common")]
        public class PersonNote
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int PersonId { get; set; }
            public string Note { get; set; }
            public int AuthorId { get; set; }
            public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
            public DateTime Created { get; set; }
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
            public DateTime RecordStartDateTime { get; set; }
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
            public DateTime RecordEndDateTime { get; set; }
        }
    }

    namespace Genistar.Organisation.Models.DataModels
    {
        public class Person
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int? TitleId { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string FirstNamePref { get; set; }
            public string MiddleName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }
            public int AddressId { get; set; }
            public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
            public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public int? PartnerId { get; set; }
            public bool Enabled { get; set; }
            public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
            public DateTime Created { get; set; }
            public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
            public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
            public DateTime RecordStartDateTime { get; set; }
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
            public DateTime RecordEndDateTime { get; set; }
            public Address Address { get; set; }
            public Title Title { get; set; }
            public Client Client { get; set; }

            public List<PersonNote> PersonNotes { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

CreateMap function

```
 CreateMap<Genistar.Organisation.Models.DataModels.Person, Genistar.Organisation.Models.User.PersonNote>()
                .ForMember(t => t.AuthorId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
                .ForMember(t => t.AuthorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName));

CreateMap<Genistar.Organisation.Models.DataModels.PersonNote, Genistar.Organisation.Models.User.PersonNote>()
                  //.ForMember(t => t.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
                  //.ForMember(t => t.PersonId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.PersonId))
                  //.ForMember(t => t.Note, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Note))
                  //.ForMember(t => t.AuthorId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.AuthorId))
                  //.ForMember(t => t.CreatedBy, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.CreatedBy))
                  //.ForMember(t => t.Created, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Created));

                .ForMember(t => t.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
               .ForMember(t => t.PersonId, opt => opt.Ignore())
               .ForMember(t => t.Note, opt => opt.Ignore())
               .ForMember(t => t.AuthorId, opt => opt.Ignore())
               .ForMember(t => t.CreatedBy, opt => opt.Ignore())
               .ForMember(t => t.Created, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Query - Please note the PersonNote returned here is of type Genistar.Organisation.Models.User.PersonNote

```
[FunctionName(nameof(GetPersonNote))]
[UsedImplicitly]
public Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "person-note/{id}")] HttpRequest req,
            int id) => _helper.HandleAsync(async () =>
                               {
                                   var personNotes = _organisationRepository.GetPersonNotes(id);
                                   return new OkObjectResult(_mapper.Map<PersonNote>(personNotes));
                               });

 public IEnumerable<PersonNote> GetPersonNotes(int personId)
 {
     var PersonNotes1 = _context.PersonNotes.Where(p => p.PersonId == personId);
     return PersonNotes1;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example here doesn't make sense, you cannot have 2 "PersonNote" classes in the same namespace. It looks like you have Entities and then separate ViewModels/DTOs, though it is/will be confusing naming them identically. If that is desired or required then I would recommend aliasing the namespaces. I.e.:

```
using Models = Genistar.Organisation.Models;
using DTOs = Genistar.Organisation.Models.DataModels;
```

so that the code is explicitly readable as to which is what.

For instance this code here doesn't make much sense:

```
public Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "person-note/{id}")] HttpRequest req,
        int id) => _helper.HandleAsync(async () =>
{
    var personNotes = _organisationRepository.GetPersonNotes(id);
    return new OkObjectResult(_mapper.Map<PersonNote>(personNotes));
});

public IEnumerable<PersonNote> GetPersonNotes(int personId)
{
    var PersonNotes1 = _context.PersonNotes.Where(p => p.PersonId == personId);
    return PersonNotes1;
}
```

I'm assuming these were extracted from 2 different classes because the first method looks like it should be dealing with the DTOs while the 2nd would be from a Repository and dealing with entities?

A couple of things do stand out. First, the repository methods should return `IQueryable<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`. The benefit of this is that it will allow you to further chain Linq expressions including allowing Automapper to reduce your set down to your DTOs and having that optimization passed down to the composed SQL.

The second thing is leveraging Automapper's `ProjectTo` method rather than `Map`. Combined with `IQueryable` this allows the mapping to be done at the SQL level:

So the repository method changes to:

```
public IQueryable<PersonNote> GetPersonNotes(int personId)
{
    var PersonNotes1 = _context.PersonNotes.Where(p => p.PersonId == personId);
    return PersonNotes1;
}
```

Then your controller code:

```
public Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "person-note/{id}")] HttpRequest req,
        int id) => _helper.HandleAsync(async () =>
    {
       var personNotes = _organisationRepository.GetPersonNotes(id).ProjectTo<DTO.PersonNote>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
       return new OkObjectResult(personNotes);
    });
```

When your repository returns `IEnumerable`, the mapper calls are going to be trying to navigate through the properties at face value based on what is eager loaded, and dealing with any proxy types EF inserts. I'm not 100% across the differences that the different EF Core versions have over EF6 but your existing code looks to be getting tripped up with a proxy type. Even so, without this there would be an extra DB hit with Automapper's `Map` call to lazy load any related entities as it traverses over the properties.

Comment: I made the changes that your suggested like making it IQuerable and using the projectTo but getting error   "stack": "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r\n   at IQueryable<TDestination> AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.ProjectTo<TDestination>(IQueryable source, IConfigurationProvider configuration, object parameters, Expression<Func<TDestination, object>>[] membersToExpand)\r\n

Comment: var personNotes = _organisationRepository.GetPersonNotes(id).ProjectTo<PersonNote>(null);

Comment: I need to pass something to constructor as it doesnt allow zero arguments

Comment: Sorry PersonNote are in different namespaces. I forgot to include the namespace.Updated the post

Comment: Ah yes, Automapper's ProjectTo is an extension method and needs the mapper's configuration reference. I keep forgetting to add that. I believe they had an alternative on the mapper instance itself.. I'm updating the example. Pass `ProjectTo` `_mapper.ConfigurationProvider` as the argument.